# JPA - Domain Class & Property not found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I'm using Spring boot with a H2 database for local dev work, the problem being encountered is with a domain class that I initially setup. It worked fine but I then renamed a property and now I receive the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property name found for type class org.rest.model.Foo"

I think the cause is that the Spring auto configuration has scanned the Domain class but hasn't detected that the property is now different and it's throwing the error.

How can I avoid this from happening as I have a number of changes that I'm implementing as I go?

Comment: It doesn't retain anything. If you rename properties you also have to fix queries. If you use `spring-data-jpa` you have to fix your `find*` method accordingly.

Comment: Can you post your repository & domain class, stating the change you made. Than we can say something more certain?

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum, your comment around updating the find* method put me on the right path. I had updated everything except the name of the find* method.

Comment: If you get an exception, POST the EXCEPTION + STACK TRACE!